# Shiny code executed without waiting for inputs from modalDialog

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog

I have a problem with shiny code being executed without waiting for user input from the modalDialog. Here's a simple example. The app has a **Print** button and an output box. When a user click button, a modalDialog should pop up asking the user what to print. If the user clicks the **Print Button 1** button, then the final printed output would be **Button 1 Print Result**. Same goes for Button 2.

```
library(shiny)


# Main app UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('print','Print')
  ,verbatimTextOutput('output')

)

# Main app server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  printVal <- reactiveVal("Should not be printing this")
  
  observeEvent(input$print,{
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        title = 'What to print?'
        ,"Decide what to print"
        ,footer = tagList(
          actionButton('btn1','Print Button 1')
          ,actionButton('btn2','Print BUtton 2')
          
        )
      )
    )
    
    output$output <- renderPrint({printVal()})
  })
  
  observeEvent((input$btn1),{
    printVal('Button 1 Print Result')
    removeModal()
  })
  observeEvent((input$btn2),{
    printVal('Button 2 Print Result')
    removeModal()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But what ends up happening is that when Print is clicked, the default value, which is set to "Should not be printing this" is being printed in the output **BEFORE** the user has a chance to click any of the buttons in the modalDialog. What I want is that the only the output should be the result of clicking button 1 or 2. But it seems shiny executes the line

```
 output$output <- renderPrint({printVal()})
```

without waiting for actions coming from modalDialog.

Basically, how can I make it so that printVal is updated from modalDialog before being used? Thanks in advance for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the `output$output` defined too early.  Try this

```
observeEvent((input$btn1),{
    output$output <- renderPrint({printVal()})
    printVal('Button 1 Print Result')
    removeModal()
  })
  observeEvent((input$btn2),{
    output$output <- renderPrint({printVal()})
    printVal('Button 2 Print Result')
    removeModal()
  })
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry - new to Stack Overflow and not familiar with the proper etiquette. I've accepted it.